# How does smart pointer choose default_delete by partial specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

unique_ptr is basically implemented as follows:

```
template <typename _Tp>    // deleter for single object
struct default_delete {
  void operator()(_Tp* ptr) const {
    delete ptr;
  }
};
template <typename _Tp>    // deleter for array
struct default_delete<_Tp[]> {
  void operator()(_Tp* ptr) const {
    delete[] ptr;
  }
};

// main template
template <typename _Tp, typename _Dp = default_delete<_Tp>>
class unique_ptr {
public:
  typedef _Tp  element_type;
  typedef _Dp  deleter_type;
  // ...
};

// array specialized
template <typename _Tp, typename _Dp>
class unique_ptr<_Tp[], _Dp> {   
public:               // ^ How did this work?
  typedef _Tp  element_type;
  typedef _Dp  deleter_type;
  // ...
};
```

When I use **int[]** as template argument, obviously this will fall into unique_ptr's array version. 
As far as I know, compiler will match Tp[] with int[], and match Dp with the default template parameter default_delete<_Tp>>. So Tp is deduced to int, and finally the template parameter list deduced will be like this in my thought:

```
<int[], default_delete<int>>
```

My question: How did the compiler select default_delete's partial specialization for delete[] ? It seems like there is no reason to choose deleter's int[] version. I think parameter Dp in specialized version and in main template are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_Tp` in the primary template and `_Tp` in the partial specialization are not the same. You could give them different names to distinguish them better.

The default template arguments are taken from the primary template and this gives the default argument

```
default_delete<_Tp>
```

for `_Dp`. `_Tp` here is the `_Tp` from the *primary template*, not from the specialization.

In the specialization, the argument given for the primary template's `_Tp` is `_Tp[]`, where the latter `_Tp` is the specialization's one.

Therefore with e.g. `unique_ptr<int[]>`, the specialization is preferred with the specialization's `_Tp` equal to `int`, but the primary template's `_Tp` is `int[]` and so the default argument for `_Dp`, which is taken from the primary template, is `default_delete<int[]>`, not `default_delete<int>`.

Answer (score 3):

Given `unique_ptr<int[]>`, the primary template is checked firstly, as the result `_Tp` is deduced as `int[]`, and `_Dp` would be `default_delete<int[]>` (from the default value.)

Then the specializations are checked. The specialization is defined as `unique_ptr<_Tp[], _Dp>`; from the deduction result got above, it's replaced as `unique_ptr<int[], default_delete<int[]>>`, then the template parameter `_Tp` and `_Dp` of the specialization are deduced as `int` and `default_delete<int[]>`. (They're independent with the template parameters of the primary template.)